# Shift right array w/ allocation in C (Abort Trap : 6)

Tags: c, arrays, macos, memory, char

I have a problem with my code. I would like to pop in first position a char '_' into a full array. I wrote this but terminal shows me a Abort Trap : 6. Could you help me?

```
//this code was deleted cause i had good answer! Sorry but is a school project and i couldn't post anything !
```

I don't know it's important to know that i use mac OSX

Comment: I'll give you one place to look.  A string of length 6 requires _7_ bytes to store, not 6. There's a null character at the end, and it's up to you to provide space for it.

Comment: Yes sorry I wrote in wrong way the string . I put in array "Hello" NOT "Hello!" but abort trap  is still there! :(

Comment: `strcat("_",temp);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: Note: `malloc(len+1)` is allocating 8 in this example and apparently  only 7 needed.

Comment: Use "gdb" debugging tool to exactly know which statement causing SEG FAULT

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `strcat` function wrong. The first argument is the destination and since you are passing a string literal it is undefined behavior.

```
strcpy(dupstr, "_");
strcat(dupstr, temp);
```

should do the trick.